# How can I prevent an attribute from being a certain value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model "User" with attribute "Username". Can I use validations to prevent a User being created with the Username "home"?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [exclusion validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  USERNAME_BLACKLIST = ['home'].freeze

  validates :username, presence: true, exclusion: { in: USERNAME_BLACKLIST }
end
```

Alternatively, you can always rely on a custom validation method, using `validate` instead of `validates`, for more complex types of validation that aren't easily expressed using built-in validators:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true

  validate :username_not_on_restricted_list

  protected

  def username_not_on_restricted_list
    errors.add(:username, :invalid) if username == 'home'
  end
end
```

You could also write a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) if you intend to reuse this functionality across multiple models.

Comment: Could you please explain what the "freeze" method accomplishes in this context?

Comment: @JoeMorano It prevents the value of the constant from being modified. Ruby warns you when assigning new values to a constant, but it doesn't prevent you from modifying those values, which is generally undesirable. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/MutableConstant